# Obtain indices of a array where 4 or more than 4 adjacent elements are 1

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I want to obtain indices of array (data) where 4 or more than 4 adjacent elements are 1:

```
import numpy as np    

data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
```

How would you do it?

The expected answer is:

```
answer = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [0, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [1, 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                   [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
```

I have converted the unwanted pixels into 0.

Comment: What is the expected output for your example? Can adjacency be in any direction, e.g. vertical, diagonal, T-shaped?

Comment: yes they can be in any direction.

Comment: I have edited my question to show the expected answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution using `numpy.ndimage`. It computes the size of adjacent regions (of `1.0`s) in the array and then replaces each pixel in the array with the size of the corresponding region. This can then be used to set all pixels in the image to zero that do not belong to region of size at least 4.

```
import scipy.ndimage.measurements as m

labels,nlabels = label(data) 
sizes = np.hstack((0,m.sum(data, labels, range(1,nlabels+1)))) 
data[sizes[labels] < 4] = 0.0
```

Comment: @simen, that last question is answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28516356/2476444) or [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28522264/2476444).

Comment: @OliverW. I know the links you provided because they are already LINKED to this question by SF. However, I am looking for solving the problem using numpy ans scipy mostly the scipy filters and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the skimage version.  A bit longer, but perhaps somewhat more explicit:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import numpy as np
from skimage.measure import label, regionprops

data = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [0, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

labels = label(data, background=0, neighbors=4)
regions = regionprops(labels)
out = np.zeros_like(data)

for r in regions:
    if r.area >= 4:
        rows, cols = r.coords.T
        out[rows, cols] = 1

print(out)
```

Comment: Also, would better to avoid for loop is not?

Comment: Not sure how you would avoid the for-loop here.  And the 4 adjacent elements can be in any shape.