# How can I keep the patch which contain all the elements 1

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches
import numpy as np

data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])

patches = extract_patches(data, patch_shape=(2, 2))
```

How can I keep the patch which contain all the elements 1?

Comment: Quick question: what do you mean keep the patch here? What would your expected output be?

Comment: The patches array has splitted the data array into 2 by 2 patches. Now I want to keep those patches if all the elements of it are 1, otherwise convert all the elements into 0.

Comment: "otherwise convert all the elements into 1." You mean 0, right? Otherwise you end up with an array full of ones.

Comment: @OliverW. I mean all the elements of one sub-array or patch as within the array patches.

Comment: I believe you are looking for something that you won't get by using `extraction_step` as none of the patches in your array `patches` are all ones. Can you add in your post the desired output based on the array `data`?

Comment: @OliverW. sorry, edited the question.

Comment: You might want to edit it again, explaining how the middle block is not recognized as a ones-patch in your definition?

Comment: @OliverW. sorry again the middle block is also included. you have known the expected answer better.

Comment: No, I don't. I've seen thus far about 5 edits to your question, and with all of them I wondered how you got the output from that dataset. I recommend that based on the current array `data` you try once again to create (manually) the array you desire and add it to your post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the corrections to your post, I believe you might be looking for a way to detect where submatrices of shape `(2,2)` are all ones. Anywhere where that condition isn't fulfilled should be zero, but priority should be given to the submatrices where that condition is fulfilled, because *submatrices can be overlapping*.

In that case, you're most likely interested in the staggered grid of that matrix that has a one in the center of each 2x2 submatrix whenever the 4 elements of that submatrix are all ones:

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches # similar to numpy's stride_tricks
>>> 
>>> data = np.array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
...                  [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
...                  [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
...                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
...                  [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
...                  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
...                  [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
>>> 
>>> # to take boundary effects into account, append ones to the right and bottom
... # modify this to `np.zeros` if boundaries are to be set to zero
... data2 = np.ones((data.shape[0]+1, data.shape[1]+1))  
>>> data2[:-1,:-1] = data
>>> vert = np.logical_and(data2[:-1,:], data2[1:,])
>>> dual = np.logical_and(vert[:,:-1], vert[:,1:]) # dual is now the "dual" graph/staggered grid of the data2 array
>>> patches = extract_patches(data2, patch_shape=(2, 2))  # could've used numpy stride_tricks too
>>> patches[dual==0] = 0
>>> patches[dual] = 1  # Give precedence to the dual positives
>>> data2[:-1, :-1].astype(np.uint8)
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]], dtype=uint8)
```

For completeness, this staggered grid form of the matrix could also be obtained easily with a *correlation* with a `np.ones((2,2))` kernel. However, that is computationally more heavy, because a lot more work has to be done (multiplications and summations) rather than simple bit-operations. The method above will outperform a correlation-based method in terms of speed.
The staggered grid `dual` above could also be generated in the following way:

```
patches = extract_patches(data, patch_shape=(2, 2))
dual = patches.all(axis=-1).all(axis=-1)
```

And you would obtain the final result with:

```
dual = patches.all(axis=-1).all(axis=-1)
patches[dual==False] = 0
patches[dual] = 1
```

It differs from the previous method in what happens at the boundaries though.

Comment: @musk not sure what you want now, those questions you link to have been answered. What's not clear about them? If you feel those questions aren't answered satisfactorily, perhaps you could consider asking a new question with a good example of input data and desired output data?

Comment: @musk, I've edited my answer, perhaps this last alternative is exactly what you meant?

Comment: Thanks for making it more understandable.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative method, using [`minimum_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.minimum_filter.html) and [`maximum_filter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.maximum_filter.html) from [`scipy.ndimage`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/ndimage.html). (The description in the question is still too vague--for me, anyway--so this is based on the result shown in @OliverW.'s answer.)

```
In [138]: from scipy.ndimage import minimum_filter, maximum_filter

In [139]: data
Out[139]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])

In [140]: m = minimum_filter(data, size=(2,2), mode='constant', origin=(-1,-1))

In [141]: result = maximum_filter(m, size=(2,2), mode='constant')

In [142]: result
Out[142]: 
array([[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

Comment: Thanks, upvoted! May I know why origin=(-1,-1) should be used?