# Extracting the elements matching the filter

Tags: numpy, scipy, scikit-image

I want to filter the indices whose footprint (3,3) consists of 1s.

```
import numpy as np
data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1]])
```

The expected answer is below, unwanted positions are set to 0s:

```
answer = np.array([[0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm basing this answer on [a very similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28516356/2476444) I wrote just a few hours ago.

```py
#from sklearn.feature_extraction.image import extract_patches  # similar to numpy's stride_tricks
from numpy.lib.stride_tricks import as_strided

data = np.array([[1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 0],
                 [1, 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 0 , 0],
                 [0, 0 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 1 , 0 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1],
                 [1, 1 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 1 , 1 , 1]])
patches = as_strided(data, shape=(data.shape[0]-2,data.shape[1]-2, 3, 3), strides=data.strides*2)
dual = patches.all(axis=-1).all(axis=-1)
patches[dual==False] = 0
patches[dual] = 1
```

The result (in `data`) is as you've shown.

The way this works is as follows:
the function `extract_patches` generates *a view* into the array `data`, which means it is *not* a copy of the actual data but uses the *strides* to generate a seemingly different array. In this case, it will generate all possible 3x3 submatrices (which can be overlapping) of the array `data`. Then, by writing `patches.all(axis=-1).all(axis=-1)`, you are first checking if the elements in the rows of the submatrices are all True (or equivalent to True in a boolean sense, so not 0, empty lists, empty dictionaries, empty tuples and a few other special cases), thereby collapsing one of the axes of this array and then with the second `.all(axis=-1)` the columns are being checked to see if they're all True.

Small example of this paragraph to clarify visually:

```py
>>> A = np.array([
... [1, 1, 0],        # -> along this row, not all elements are 1: so `all` along the last axis will return False
... [1, 1, 1],        # -> along this row, all elements are 1: so `all` along the last axis (axis=-1) will return True
... [1, 1, 1]])
>>> A.all(axis=-1)
array([False,  True,  True], dtype=bool)  # so it is done along the last axis, along the rows
>>> A.all(axis=-1).all(axis=-1)
False
```

So this array `dual` now has a "1" (True actually) for every 3x3 submatrix that was full of ones. Those submatrices are overlapping however, so you first want to set the patches all to 0 whenevery any of these 3x3 submatrices was not all ones (that's the one-to-last line in the first code block: `patches[dual==False] = 0`) and *then* you can apply the ones again in each 3x3 submatrix that originally had all ones.
The alternatives are to correlate with a `kernel = np.ones((3,3))` or to take multiple bitwise operations into account (like in the other answer), but that last method becomes very difficult to write when the array's dimensions grow beyond simply `(2,2)`.

Comment: @simen, considering the links you refer, I guess that you are also the user "musk" (from the question I linked). If so, you might want to ask one of the Stackoverflow moderators to merge your accounts. In any case, both questions you link to are accepted. If they didn't do what you want, you should explain more thoroughly why the answers don't do what you wanted. Similar situation here: can you explain whymy answer doesn't do *exactly* what you asked for in your *original post*?

Comment: I am no longer interested in solving my question using sklearn. I am looking for the way of solving it implementing the way in the answers I have shared above.

Comment: The links are already linked to this question, and I am familiar with your answer to the user musk because that question is also linked to my question.

Comment: @simen in both questions I reference the use of numpy's stride tricks. I've updated the answer to *only* use numpy libraries. I hope you understand now that `extract_patches` from `sklearn` is equivalent to numpy's `as_strided`.

Comment: Since your answer is also producing the expected answer, I have aceepted it., good bye